# How would you do a class agnostic list view for your website?

Tags: java, list, oop, web, model-view-controller

Working on an OOP (object oriented programming) language like Java I would like to implement a way to list any object from my model on a view (a web, built on some view engine like thymeleaf or similar.

To list 1 single class I only need to instantiate an `ArrayList<MyClass>` bind to the view and show the data in a specific designed table (equal number of columns than properties, for-each item in list a proper row in the table)

Would it be possible to implement a: 1 column For-each property in the class structure?

This is the view structure kind that I'm trying:

```html
    <table>
        <thead><tr>
            <td th:each="column : ${columns}" th:text="${column.tag}"></td>
        </tr></thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr th:each="elem : ${elements}">
                <td th:text="..."></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

This is the controller where I'm building the sample data:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/listurl", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView multiColumn(Model model){

        List<Column> columns = Arrays.asList(new Column[]{
                new Column("textprop", 4),
                new Column("booleanprop", 2),
                new Column("dateprop", 3),
                new Column("integerprop", 1),
                new Column("decimalprop", 5)
        });
        List<Element> elements = Arrays.asList(new Element[]{
                new Elemento( "Entry", true, new Date(), 1, 2.2)
        });

        Collections.sort(columns, new Comparator<Column>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Column o1, Column o2) {
                if (o1.getOrder() == o2.getOrder()) {
                    return 0;
                } else {
                    return (o1.getOrder() > o2.getOrder() ? 1 : - 1);
                }
            }});

        model.addAttribute("columns", columns);
        model.addAttribute("elements", elements);
        return new ModelAndView("listview");
    }
```

So I've come up with this Column class which I define with 2 properties:
`String tag` and `int order`
The Element class contains one property of each class, I give the property name to the column tag.

Comment: but what do you want to see? a string representation? an icon? something else?

Comment: @AminM properties could be text, numbers of varied types, booleans that i could parse or format on readable "Yes/No" but this is not the main problem that i have (I could interpose some kind of dto that parses everything to strings). I wonder how to handle a variable number column representation.

Comment: I've updated with some sample code that I'm writing to give this question a try.